# Excel If operator with two semicolon

Tags: java, excel, operator-keyword, ternary-operator

I must translate some excel code into JasperReport, and there is some syntax that is unknown to me.
here is the operation into one of the cell:

```
=IF(B106<5000;9,5+B106*15,5/4999;IF(B106>=100000;80;16,69*LN(B106)-117,15))
```

I dont know what the semicolon around the "80" mean:

```
F(B106>=100000;80;
```

I've translated the debut of the operation like this:

```
$F{B106}.intValue() < 5000 ?  new Double(9.5) + $F{B106}.intValue() * new Double(15.5) / 4999
```

But I'm stuck with the two semi-colon...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this formula the semi-colon is a **field separator** and the comma appears to be a **decimal separator**